# youtube-dl: how to use the options and get the output to a variable

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I have been trying to use youtube-dl using python instead of console. I am trying to get some information of a video such as available video formats, title, duration of the video etc. None of the options are working except `listformats`. So I tried different combinations of the options described in the documentation. Unfortunately nothing is working. I only see the list of video formats from `listformats`. Also, the output is only showing in the console but I need the output info in a variable such as `video_details`.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {
    '-v': True,
    'format': '-f',
    'print_json': True,
    'listformats': '--list-formats',
    'getfilename': '--get-filename',
    '--get-filename': True,
    '-e': True,
}

ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts)
video_details = ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to extract the information.
Use the `extract_info`-method instead of `download` and it will work!

Comment: `youtube_dl.YoutubeDL().extract_info('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc', download=False)` this seems to work. Thanks

Comment: Great! Glad to help you! :)